# Ruby - validate user input against allowed characters

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

i am stuck at validating user input.
i have set of allowed characters "R G B Y" and i am asking for user input. I want to validate if user inputs ONLY characters that are allowed ("R G B Y").

User can input whatever he or she wants as long as input include allowed characters, for example:

```
user_input1 = "R R R Y"
user_input2 = "Y Y B G"
```

and so on...

i am totally stuck, i tried with regex:

```
/[RGBY]/
```

it is working fine if user inputs allowed characters, but if there will be a mix of allowed and not allowed characters, regex won't catch it :( for example:

```
wrong_user_input = "Z Z R Y"
```

i know regex is overkill for this simple task but i cannot think of something else in this moment. 
any help would be appreciated....
thanks!

Comment: Is "RRRY" also allowed, or should there always be space inbetween?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/^[RGBY ]+$/` as a pattern, so that from the beginning (^) to the end ($)  (not partially) whole characters are consisted of allowed characters (R, G, B, Y, or space):

```
>> "Z Z R Y" =~ /^[RGBY ]+$/
=> nil
>> "R R R Y" =~ /^[RGBY ]+$/
=> 0
```

Comment: thanks, i was stuck so much that i forgot about beginning and end of a string :) this totally solved my problem, thank you so much now i can move on!

Answer (score 2):

There was a related question a while ago, and this came out as the fastest solution :

```
"Z Z R Y".count("^RGBY ") == 0
#=> false
"R G R Y".count("^RGBY ") == 0
#=> true
```

It counts characters that are not `R,G,B,Y` or space.

Comment: thanks for answering, for what i am doing , speed really doesn't matter much

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more ways, some of which do not employ a regex.

**Negation of: the string contains a character other than `"R"`, `"G"`, `"B"`, `"V"` and `" "`**

```
!('Z Z R Y' =~ /[^RGBY ]/) #=> false
!('R R R Y' =~ /[^RGBY ]/) #=> true
```

This avoids the need for anchors.

**Use String#delete to remove target characters and then see if any characters are left**

```
'Z Z R Y'.delete('RGBY ').empty? #=> false
'R R R Y'.delete('RGBY ').empty? #=> true
```

One variant of this is to use [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
'Z Z R Y'.tr('RGBY ', '').empty? #=> false
'R R R Y'.tr('RGBY ', '').empty? #=> true
```

Another is to use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regex:

```
'Z Z R Y'.gsub(/[RGBY ]/, '').empty? #=> false
'R R R Y'.gsub(/[RGBY ]/, '').empty? #=> true
```

**Convert the string to an array of characters and use a logical comparison**

```
arr = ['R', 'G', 'B', 'Y', ' ']

('Z Z R Y'.chars - arr).empty? #=> false
('R R R Y'.chars - arr).empty? #=> true
```